# Creating MQTT broker C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, mqtt, .net-6.0

I want to create new broker on custom port. Problem is that every time I create broker it just wont start.

System is Windows 11.

Using .Net 6.0.

MQTT I am using is mosquitto 2.0.15.

MQTTnet version is 4.2.1.781.

```
 class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create and configure the MQTT broker
            var optionsBuilder = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
                .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1884);
            var mqttServer = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttServer(optionsBuilder.Build());
            try
            {
                await mqttServer.StartAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("MQTT broker started on port 1884.");

            // Create a client to subscribe to a topic
            var subscriberClient = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttClient();
            var subscriberOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                .WithClientId("SubscriberClient")
                .WithTcpServer("localhost", 1884)
                .Build();
            await subscriberClient.ConnectAsync(subscriberOptions);
            await subscriberClient.SubscribeAsync(new MqttTopicFilterBuilder()
                .WithTopic("$SYS/broker/clients/active")
                .Build());
            subscriberClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += async e =>
            {
                var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload);
                Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {payload}");
            };

            // Create a client to publish messages to the topic
            var publisherClient = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttClient();
            var publisherOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                .WithClientId("PublisherClient")
                .WithTcpServer("localhost", 1884)
                .Build();
            await publisherClient.ConnectAsync(publisherOptions);

            Console.WriteLine("Publisher client connected.");

            // Publish messages to the topic
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var message = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
                    .WithTopic("mytopic")
                    .WithPayload(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Message {i}"))
                    .Build();
                await publisherClient.PublishAsync(message);

                Console.WriteLine($"Published message {i} to 'mytopic'.");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            // Stop the broker
            await mqttServer.StopAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("MQTT broker stopped.");
        }
    }
```

I disabled firewall.
Port 1884 is not used by anything.

**EDIT** I dropped this topic as i found another anwser to my issue

Comment: I'm confused why you say you are using mosquitto 2.0.15, when you are trying to start your own broker in the application, not connect to an external broker. Also just saying "It won't start" doesn't give us much to work with, are there any error messages?

Comment: @hardillb you are rightly confused. I was just stupid and tried to create new mosquitto broker. I am quite new to mqtt and at the time didnt understand what mosquitto even is...

Comment: You can always delete a question if needed (link at the bottom near the edit button)

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var optionsBuilder = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
                .WithDefaultEndpoint()
                .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1884);
```

**EDIT**

[Example](https://github.com/SeppPenner/SimpleMqttServer/blob/master/src/SimpleMqttServer/MqttService.cs#L177)

No listener is registered when `options.DefaultEndpointOptions.IsEnabled` is false.

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/master/Source/MQTTnet/Implementations/MqttTcpServerAdapter.cs#L46)

In `new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()` the `options.DefaultEndpointOptions.IsEnabled` is `false`.

`WithDefaultEndpoint()` set `options.DefaultEndpointOptions.IsEnabled` to `true`.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76804367/edit) the question to add an explanation of why this answers the question

Comment: @hardillb they speak on a language they understand